# BizTalk WCF-webhttp and IIS: How to handle authentication and authorization, ASP.NET compatibility or custom?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, biztalk

I have published a WCF service using the WCF Service Publishing wizard (which appears to be the only way I can find to create a WCF service for use by a WCF-webhttp receive adapter). I want to use ASP.NET authentication in IIS.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-services-and-aspnet) article:

> ...the WCF security model does not adhere to any URL-based authorization rules specified in System.Web’s  configuration element...WCF’s ASP.NET compatibility mode is suitable for scenarios that do not require the ability to host outside of IIS or to communicate over protocols other than HTTP. WCF’s ASP.NET compatibility mode is enabled at the application level through the following configuration (located in the application’s Web.config file):

```
<system.serviceModel>  
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />  
</system.serviceModel>
```

However, I get the "The service cannot be activated because it does not support ASP.NET compatibility" error when a client request is made to the service. According to [articles](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-WCF-The-service-cannot-be-activated-because-it-does-not-support-ASPNET-compatibility.aspx) I have found on this, the AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode attribute must be added to the service class at design time. How can this be done if using the WCF Publishing wizard? I cannot find any articles explaining how to create a custom BizTalk WCF service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to follow [this](https://phidiax.com/blog/post/securing-biztalk-wcf-receive-locations) walkthrough to build a custom behavior. The custom behavior inspects the user security principal of the incoming request to the WCF Service and determines if it meets the requirements of the ASP.NET authorization requirements. This allows you to control the WCF service/site authorization from within IIS.